# Magento 2: Rearrange the Checkout page Summary Sidebar

Tags: magento2, checkout, xml

Currently, the Summary on the Checkout page displays the totals at the top of the summary and the cart items beneath it. I would like it the other way around – to place the cart items at the top of the summary sidebar and the totals beneath.

If I rearrange the `summary` child items `totals` and `cart_items` in `Magento_2_Installation/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`, then the items are reaaranged how I'd like them (items above totals).

Obviously, updating the core files isn't the correct way to do it. So, I created another `checkout_index_index.xml` and placed it here: `Magento_2_Installation/app/design/frontend/mike/mikesite/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`. Unfortunately, this doesn't rearrange the child items of Summary and has no effect at all.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                <!-- <item name="totals" /> was here originally -->

                                                <item name="itemsBefore" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="details" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="thumbnail" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before_details</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">after_details</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>

                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="itemsAfter" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- merge your components here -->
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals</item>
                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">totals</item>
                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/summary/totals</item>
                                                    </item>
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- sort order for this totals is configured on admin panel-->
                                                        <!-- Stores->Configuration->SALES->Sales->General->Checkout Totals Sort Order -->
                                                        <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/subtotal</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Cart Subtotal</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="shipping" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping</item>
                                                                <item name="notCalculatedMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Not yet calculated</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/grand-total</item>
                                                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total</item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>                                                    
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you able to rearrange them ?

Comment: It works if I do it in the core files.

Answer (score 13):

In my theme override of `app/design/frontend/<Vendorname>/<theme>/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` I used sort order to rearrange the child items, where a lower number (starting from 0) indicates a child should appear earlier in the sequence. This code moved the totals below the items for me:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sidebar" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="totals" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">99</item>
                                                </item>
                                                <item name="cart_items" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in checkout_cart_index.xml, it moves the cart summary below the items (tested with Magento 2.1.2):

```
<move element="cart.summary" destination="checkout.cart.items" after="checkout.cart.form"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control the position using **sortOrder**.
Refer to this article to understand the concept : https://inviqa.com/blog/technical-guide-magento-2-checkout