# move discount section below the shipping div in checkout page

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to move discount div to below the shipping method div. I tried it with xml. I tried it to move like this : `<move element="checkout.discount" destination="checkout.cart.methods" after="checkout.cart.methods.onepage.bottom"/>`
But it is not working.

**Situation** : Right now discount section is below the payment method and right side. It is default view.

**What exactly I want** : I want discount section below the shipping method. It will be middle of the page.

Comment: Might this will help you.     https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/126072/magento-2-rearrange-the-checkout-page-summary-sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you have to use jQuery. I think xml move tag is not working for this.

Go to

> onepage.phtml

file and put this code at the end of the file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 require([
    'jquery'
], function($) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#iwd_opc_discount" ).insertAfter( "#onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load" )
      }, 2500);
   }
 );
//]]>
</script>
```

Suppose `#iwd_opc_discount` is your discount div id.

`#onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load` is your shipping div id.

Edited : **XML is also working for it**. @ravi soni's link is also working.

Comment: This is work for me. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link you can read and implement it accordingly.
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_customize.html